# Because of the necessity of property names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code and html for trigger radio button
it's work and don't have any problem,"However, should there be a name property" 
when I delete name property is don't work
What is the reason?

```
<input type="radio" name="e"  />
<input type="radio" name="e" />
<input type="radio" name="e" />

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type=radio]').change(function (event) {
                //I've used classes based on values, which works as long as
                //the values are consistent and don't contain spaces!
                console.log(this);
                $.filter(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
            });
  });
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: It doesn't look like the name has anything to do with the javascript, so I guess you're talking about when the form submits, and yes, then the elements should have names, but not all the same name? The comments in the script however makes no sense at all ?

Comment: Radio buttons should have the same name, since that's how it determines which ones are in the same group.

Comment: i have 3 radio,and when click any radio other radio is unchecked,when i remove property is not work and 3 radio is checked

Comment: *"A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name."*  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#successful-controls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio buttons have to have a `name` attribute. The name is used to determine which buttons are part of the same group, so that clicking one of them unchecks the previous one. This grouping is the difference between radio buttons and checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

> you define radio button groups with the name property

Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form.

The whole purpose of a radio button is to enable the user to make one selection - and one only - from a list. If you wanted the user to make multiple selections, you wouldn't use a radio button - you'd use a checkbox.

Anyway, because the user can only make one selection from our group of radio buttons, all radio buttons in that group need to share the same name. This is how we group the list together - they all share the same name. This tells the form handler the name of the group, and the value of the selected radio button.

REFERENCE

http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm

Answer (score 0):

`name` attribute is the same for all radio buttons that are considered to be part of the same group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without name but that is not a proper way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(event) {
        console.log(this);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        $('input[type=radio]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/qe37J/1/)